# How do I set a full width background like this picture?

Tags: html, css, background

[image]

There is a background image with 4 different colors as you see. I'm not sure how to turn this into HTML so that it covers the whole page (horizontally). I  have the following code:

```css
body{
background: url(http://uupload.ir/files/y7l4_bg.png) repeat-x;
}


.upper{
background: url(http://uupload.ir/files/ur8m_cloud.png);
height:600px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- upper section -->
   <div class="upper">
    This is the upper section
 </div>
<!--end upper section-->

</body>
```

But clearly it doesn't work as expected. What am I missing here?

Comment: sorry...didnt get you...what is that you actually want?

Comment: I need a proper way to set this background image.

Comment: Are you trying to recreate the picture you posted or only trying to get the cloud image?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    background: url(http://uupload.ir/files/y7l4_bg.png) repeat-x;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.upper{
    background: url(http://uupload.ir/files/ur8m_cloud.png);
    height:600px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- upper section -->
   <div class="upper">
    This is the upper section
 </div>
<!--end upper section-->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply the body isn't tall enough to show all of that image as the only thing in it is the upper div.

```
body {
    background: url(http://uupload.ir/files/y7l4_bg.png) repeat-x;
    height: 2513px; /* image height*/
}
```

See this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rxpgt7om/1/)

Regardless, using a massive background image like that is probably not the optimum method, especially when that layout and presentaton could be simply achieved with minimal HTML & CSS.